# Checking whether $\mathbb C^n$ is semisimple or not

Tags: banach-algebras

Consider $\mathbb C^n$ as a Banach algebra over $\mathbb C$. Is it semisimple?

A Banach algebra is semisimple if the intersection of all maximal ideals of it is ${0}$.

I can't figure out what are the maximal ideals of $\mathbb C^n$.  How do I solve it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about putting $I_k:=\{x\in\mathbb{C}^n\mid x_k=0\}$?

They are surely ideals, they are maximal since their dimension is $n-1$, and their intersection is zero.

Comment: One more way to answer this : $\mathbb C ^n$ is a $C^*$ algebra and every $C^*$ algebra is semisimple.